# HTTP response headers over clients

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, http

So I am little confused on the behaviour of HTTP headers. My question is:

If I am running an API off a server. If a client makes a request, and i respond to the client via the server by setting a header in the form of:

```
response.header.<some_header> = <some_value>
```

will this header persist for all clients (ie some computer, and then another computer, etc), or is this header response unique to the client making the request?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The `response` object is only sent to the client that made a request in the first place. In fact you said the answer in your question yourself:

"If a client makes a request, and I respond to the client via the server"

In general if a client made a request, the server can only respond the the client that made the request. Hope this answers your question. For more information on http headers you should read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers).

Comment: Great thank you! I will take a read. So if, for example, in express i set a response.header.Authorization = <token>, this will not be exposed to any other client other than the one making the request (you probably answered this, but i wont be satisfied unless this EXACT question is clarified lol)

Comment: That is correct, it will only be sent the client that made the request. However, it can be interpreted by someone else unless the response is sent over a SSL, i.e. over `https`.